# firefox Javascript document.write(onclick) reference error undefined function

Tags: javascript, firefox, onclick, undefined, document.write

I have 2 frames on a webpage with the left frame being populated with a list of country names from javascript object.  Each country is also an object within the main object and has 4 name/value properties.  I am using the following function attached to the body onload:

```
        function populateList() {
            var list = top.frames[0].document;
            list.open()
            list.write("<h2>Countries</h2><ul>");
            for ( name in euMem ){
                if( typeof name !== 'object' ){
                    list.write( '<li><a href=\"\" onclick=\"updateFrame(\'' + name + '\');\">' + name + '</a></li>' );
                }
            }
            list.write("</ul>");
            list.close();
        }
```

When a user clicks on one of the country names on the left it is intended to run this function:

```
        function updateFrame( country ) {
            var infoFrame = top.frames[1].document;
            infoFrame.open();
            var size = Object.size(euMem[country]);
            infoFrame.writeln("<h1>Information for " + country + "</h1>");
            for( prop in euMem[country] ){
                infoFrame.writeln(prop + " : " + euMem[country][prop] + "<br>" );
            }
            infoFrame.close();
        }
```

Which seems to work fine on Chrome, but on Firefox I get reference error stating that updateFrame is not defined.  When I hardcode updateFrame directly into the HTML it works without a hitch on firefox but when it is written with document.write I get the reference error.

Why won't this work on Firefox?

**EDIT:** 
Here is a quick script I wrote to test the most basic version of this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>InfoPane</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(name){
            alert(name);
        }

        function load(){
            document.write("<button onclick='test('John Doe');'>Alert Me!</button>");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">

</body>
</html>
```

The above does not work on Firefox...

I was able to get this code to work as a basic example, but could not expand it into my code above to get it to function:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>InfoPane</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            alert(this.name);
        }

        function load(){
            var btn = document.createElement('button'); 
            btn.name = 'John Doe'; 
            btn.onclick = test; 
            btn.innerHTML = 'Alert Me!'; 
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load();">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Why do you use frames? 2. How do you embed the script and where?

Comment: I'm using frames because it is a class assignment that requires us to use frames.  The script is being embedded in the HTML file for the first frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Firefox is following the spec but Chrome is not.

In your most basic version, the page defines a property on the global object whose name is "test" and whose value is a function.  Then the load event handler runs and calls `document.write`, which does an implicit `document.open`.  Since the document is no longer loading at that point, that blows away the old document's contents.  So far this is all the same in Firefox and Chrome.

Where they differ is that per spec, and in Firefox, `open` on a document that is no longer loading will create a new global object for the document.  Of course this new global object has no property named `test`.  On the other hand, Chrome keeps the old global (and various other state from the old document, like event handlers, interval timers, etc).

If you plan to rewrite documents with `document.open` and want them to be able to call utility functions, you want to put those utility functions in some other frame whose global you won't keep blowing away.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I had the problem moving to an external file as well because it was linked within the frame that was getting blown away.  I updated the links to window.parent and moved the script to the frameset and was able to successfully get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

try using `window.parent.updateFrame(...)`

Comment: This did not work.  I've also tried externally linking to the script with no luck.